# The difference between `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions` and `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode`

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am looking for some documentation to understand the difference between `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions` and `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode`.

When do we need to set these parameters and what is the use of these?

```
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=500
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hive's Dynamic Partitioning allows the users to create partitions without having to provide the partition values. The partition values are determined from their corresponding input column values during query execution.

The number of partitions created will be proportional to the varied set of column values. This inturn will create burden for the HDFS namenode and Hive Metastore.

These properties

```
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode
```

are meant to have them under control by limiting the number the partitions that can be created by Dynamic Partitioning.

`hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions`: The maximum number of partitions allowed to be created in total by one dynamic partition insert.

Dynamic partitions are created only through `INSERT`. The `INSERT` query may triggger either a Map only job or a MapReduce job based on the DML.

`hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode`: The maximum number of partitions allowed to be created by each mapper or reducer node taking part in the insert job.

Setting `500` as the value for both the properties as mentioned in the question will let only one mapper/reducer to run failing others.

As a best practice,

```
hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions ~= n * hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode
```

where `n` is the number of mapper(s) and (or) reducer(s) required for the job.

Comment: Hi , One more clarification needed. hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=500 - is the number indicates total partitions can be crated. Suppose if it is per day partition, we can create maximum of 365 partitions in a year? Is that right understanding? Also hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=100 - In one node we may run multiple mapreduce jobs and this will create 100 partitions per mapreduce job or each node will create 100 partitions (suppose if I am running 2 mapreduce jobs in a node, each will create 50 partitions). Sorry for long comment and really appreciate your help.

Comment: Both the values are meant for a single insert. They are not global. let's say a script runs daily to insert data into the table, this insert query creates dynamic partitions and takes up 5 reducers. The first property makes sure that not more than 500 partitions in total are created, and the second property ensures no single reducer creates more than 500 partitions (assuming both values are set to 500). And when run for next day, the values are replenished.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.